# Compiling a C++ program with g++

Tags: c++, windows, g++

I am having issues compiling my C++ program on g++ on Windows. My program is comprised of of the following files: one cpp file, two header files, and an asm file in MASM format. I tried using the following command to compile the x64 PE file:

```
g++ test.asm test.cpp -o test.exe
```

I am getting the following exception:
file format not recognized; treating as linker script.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `g++` isn't going to recognize masm. For asm it typically uses gas format. You could either convert it to gas, or use Visual Studio Community to compile it as is.

Comment: I have a really long string variable, and unfort in C++ it only supports up to 65535 in length, therefore visual studio isn't an option, unless i switch up the string into two variables, but that's not ideal. I also want to automate compilation at some point. I'll look into gas to see if that's possible.

Comment: I just created a string that was 65537 characters in VS2022. 65535 must be a g++ limitation then I guess.

Comment: Push it to 65538 @Ted, let it all hang out.

Comment: _I also want to automate compilation at some point._ You can do that with the Microsoft compiler.  It's called `CL.EXE` and is perfectly happy to be invoked from the command line, from a batch file or from a PowerShell script.  Microsoft also provide a batch file called `vcvarsall.bat` to set up the requisite environment variables.  Or (better) you can create a Visual Studio project and build it from the command line with `MSBuild`.

Comment: *I have a really long string variable, and unfort in C++ it only supports up to 65535 in length*. That's odd. I tried it on Visual Studio 2022 and the max length of `std::string` is reported as 9223372036854775807 on my 64-bit Windows 11 system. How did you come up with 65535?

Answer (score 0):

There are different dialects of assembler. MSVC uses MASM while GCC uses GAS.

If your `.asm` file's format isn't understood by GCC try a different assembler like [JWasm](http://jwasm.github.io/), [UASM](http://www.terraspace.co.uk/uasm.html), [SASM](http://dman95.github.io/SASM/) or [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) to compile it to COFF object file (e.g. `jwasm -coff -win64 test.asm -Fo test.o`) and then use GCC to link your C++ program with it.